# Stringify a JSON with escape characters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a code similar to the below. The output I get is `{"test": "\n"}`  which is fine and correct, but I actually want an output exactly like the one I passed to the procedure: `'{"test": "\\n"}'`.

The important thing here is the escape character that is used.
The current output won’t work as a valid JSON string if you just copy-paste it and I want the output to be similar to the one passed to the procedure so that it can be copy-pasted and work out of the box.

Please note the code below is a very simplified version of what I have and in fact, the input JSON has many fields and is hierarchical.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sys.test_proc;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sys.test_proc(IN input JSON)
BEGIN
  SELECT input;
END //
DELIMITER ;

SET @test_input = '{"test": "\\n"}';

CALL sys.test_proc(CAST(@test_input AS JSON));
```

Comment: \\ will escape \. Use \\\\

Comment: The information about chars quotings is lost, and you cannot restore it. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c09e27cec65c8b4080f023b33296bd44

Comment: Why do you want to double escape `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can use the built-in `REPLACE` function to add the missing `\` characters before returning the result, and this will take care of all the inner JSON fields across the whole hierarchy:

```
SELECT REPLACE(input, '\\', '\\\\');
```